# Need help cleaning up fibonacci sequence using C++ please

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I'm still very new to C++ still and decided to make a fibonacci sequence. It worked (Woo!) but it doesn't work as well as I would like it to.

what I mean by that is say for example I told my program to count the first 10 terms of the sequence I will get

"0, 1, 1" and then I have to press enter for each additional number until it hits ten in which case the program returns 0 and ends.

How do I get the program to display all the numbers I want to without hitting enter for each additional one?

Here is my script:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int FibNum;
    cout << "How many numbers of the Fibonacci Sequence would you like to see? \n\n";
    cin>> FibNum;
    cin.ignore();
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    cout << "Fibonacci Sequence up to " << FibNum << " terms.\n\n";
    cout << a << "\n" << b << "\n";

    for (int c = 2; c < FibNum; c++) {
        int d = a + b;
        cout << d;
        cin.ignore();
        a = b;
        b = d;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.s. Also if you notice anything terrible I'm doing please feel free to correct me, I'm very aware I'm probably doing a lot wrong, I'm just trying to learn. :]

Comment: Move `c.ignore();` out of the loop: it waits until a character is entered (if you enter, e.g., `123456` it will let the loop run 7 times, once for each digit and once for the newline).

Comment: @DietmarKühl, thank you, that does work, however, it results in an equally bad problem, now all numbers display as "12358132134" instead of 
1
2
3
5
etc.. Is there any proper fix to this or should I try adding a "\n" into the loop?

EDIT: I just decided to add << "\n"; after "cout << d;" in the loop and it solved things up well enough for me.

Comment: Surely you can solve that problem yourself.

Comment: Just add a newline (`'\n'`) after each of the digits: `std::cout << d << '\n';`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Alright, I did just that, I was just looking if there was a more effiecient way, but I guess just adding a "\n" is as effecient as it gets, haha. Thanks again :]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

1) Remove `int c = 2;` as you're re-defining `c` inside the `for` loop.

2) Drop the line `cin.ignore();`: in your `for` loop: that will fix your "enter" problem; that line waits for some input then ignores it.

3) Put some white space in your output: e.g. `cout << d << ' '` so your numbers are separated.

4) [Acknowledge vincent_zhang] Consider moving to `uint64_t` as your data type for `a`, `b`, and `d`. This is a standard type in C++11. It's a 64 bit unsigned integer type; adequate for a large number of terms.

and a small thing, bordering on personal opinion,

5) Use `++c` instead of `c++` as the former will never run slower as, conceptually at least, post-increment has to take a copy of the original value.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the previous answers,

1. To better format the output,  add white space by changing this

   ```
   cout << d;
   ```

   to

   ```
   cout << d << " ";
   ```
2. You may want to change the type of `a`, `b` and `d` from `int` to `double` to prevent overflow.

   (If you let `FibNum=100` in your code, you should be able to observe overflow, meaning that you are going to get some incorrect numbers toward the end of the sequence.)

Comment: +1 for recommending data change and inspiring me to talk about the new C++11 data types. Note also that `double` is precise in integer arithmetic up to very large numerical values.

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't know much about C++11 but will go do some research;) Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Move cin.ignore() out of the loop then you dont need to enter to print all the 10 numbers of Fibonacci series